# Why does <?= work only sometimes where <?php works?

Tags: php

Inside the body of an html document I have something like this:

```
<?=str_replace(' ', '_', $result[0]['something'])?>
```

This works perfectly fine. In the same document I have this:

```
<?php if(!empty($result[0]['something'])) { echo "Hello"; } else { echo "&nbsp;"; }?>
```

Which also works fine, but it slightly bothers me that I am using `<?=` in one place and `<?php` in another. When I try to change the `if` code to become:

```
<?=if(!empty($result[0]['something'])) { echo "Hello"; } else { echo "&nbsp;"; }?>
```

or

```
<?= if(!empty($result[0]['something'])) { echo "Hello"; } else { echo "&nbsp;"; }?>
```

Both result in a *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in....*

I've attempted to find some documentation on the respective differences between `<?php` and `<?=` as a php opening tag but all I get is data on short tags - which this is not. Can someone explain this behavior for me?

Comment: `<?=` expects an expression, not a statement.

Comment: There was a short `<?` but it is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?=` is like `<?php echo`. You can't `echo` an `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you. Nice clear and clean explanation. Much appreciated!